# digits of the result of Math.random()

Tags: javascript, random

```
for (let i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    console.log("length-result:", (Math.random() + "").slice(2).length)
}
```

If you execute this code snippet, you will find that most of the results are less than `18`.

However, theoretically speaking, the last digit of the result of `random()` only has a ten-percent opportunity to be `0`. It means, only ten percents of the `length-result`s can be less than `18`.

Live snippet:

```js
// Why are results of length 20 rare, rather than occurring ~90% of the time?

for (let i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
  const str = Math.random() + '';
  tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<tr><td>${str.length}</td><td>${str}</td></tr>`);
}
```

```css
td {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can you tell me what caused this behavior of `Math.random`?

Comment: You are measuring the length of the string not the randomness of the digits it contains.

Comment: Math.random aims to distribute results uniformly by magnitude, not precision

Comment: Zero's at the end of numbers don't exist, unless you make them. So, you could say they got rid of the end zeros. `Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `0.9999` with `9` repeating, never `1`.

Comment: Another illustrative snippet: `for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      const str = Math.random() + '';
      if (str.length > 23) {
        console.log(str);
      }
    }`

Comment: Although the algorithm is not specified in spec for Math.Random, it seems all browsers have settled on [`xorshift128+`](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/xorshiftplus.pdf) as the algorithm of choice. This algorithm works over *bits*, not decimal values. You are observing artefacts of the conversion of these bits into a decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the number of digit after the decimal point. It's not related to random.

JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers (64 bits), following the international IEEE 754 standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

From that link, in section: **Character representation**:

> The original binary value will be preserved by converting to decimal
>   and back again using:[38]
>
> - 5 decimal digits for binary16
> - 9 decimal digits for binary32
> - 17 decimal digits for binary64 -> used in javascript
> - 36 decimal digits for binary128

Answer (score -1):

You are checking the length of the string from `Math.random()`. Here is a snippet that shows the distribution of the first digit.

```js
var counts = {};
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { counts[i+""] = 0; }
for(var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
  counts[(Math.random() + "").slice(2).charAt(0)]++;
}
console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score -1):

`Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `.9` repeating, never `1`. This means if you want a random number between 0 and 5, say for an array that contains the sides of dice, you would do:

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
console.log(num);
```

If you want a number between 1 and 6 you would do like:

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
console.log(num);
```

Of course, you should know the `Math.floor()` rounds down any number, removing the decimals.